# What are the differences between awkward, embarrassed, and embarrassing？

Tags: word-choice

What are the differences between awkward, embarrassed, and embarrassing？ Could native speakers please explain them for me and teach me how to use them？ Thank you very much！

Answer (score 1):

### **Common**

1. All of them (Awkward, Embarrassed and Embarrassing) are adjectives.

### Differences betwwen (Embarrassed & Embarrassing)

*1. Embarrassed is used when someone wants to explain their feeling.*

E.g 1) I was so `Embarrassed` when I saw they were kissing each other infront of me.

E.g 2) She told me that I made her `Embarrassed` infront of others when I asked her to be quiet.

*2. Embbarrassing is used when someone wants to explain how something or somebody is and what kind of feeling they are giving to them (They "Somebody or Something" are the reason why you feel like this.)*

E.g 1) The presentation was `Embbarrassing`.

E.g 2) My birthday movie was `Embarrassing`.

● You can also combine and use them togater.

E.g 1) I was so `Embarrassed` when I saw they were kissing each other infront of me. That was too `Embarrssing!`

E.g 2) My birthday movie was `Embarrassing`, It makes me `Embarrassed` each time I decide to watch.

### Differences between (Awkward & Embarrassed, Embarrassing)

*1. Awkward has more than one meaning like : (difficult, SYN embarrassing, not helpful, etc).*
E.g) Today teacher asked some kind of Awkward questions.

*But (Embarrassing, Embarrassed) has just one meaning (feeling ashamed or shy).*

You can also see dictionaries for more examples:

1. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awkward
2. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/embarrassing